# Create/Update JIRA request based on results stored in CSV

Tags: rest, csv, jenkins, cassandra, jira

I have a Jenkins job that runs the Selenium tests. The results are then stored in a CSV file and then fed to Cassandra. My requirement is to create JIRA request if the test fails either by analyzing the CSV file or from Cassandra. Please suggest the possible approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Jira API + CSV Reader or Cassandra API

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/